# PHP how to update info about checkbox in simple form

Tags: php, database, forms

I am doing simple forms which user can create by own. For ex. you are Mr Smith and you want to create simple form including 3 input fields. Text area, radio, and checkbox. User choose which input should be used and create form which people can fill in - like google forms

text area is simple and work properly but my problem is how to do the same with checkbox and radio... Too difficult

There is problem with update info about radio and checkbox

```
$tab = $request->slug;

    foreach ($tab as $key => $value){
        $custom = CustomFields::where([
            ['form_id', $id],
            ['slug', $key],
        ])->update(['name' => $value, 'slug' => str_slug($value)]);

    }
```

Comment: Actually you should check for each key for radio and checkboxes if it has a sub array (means multiple occurance of the fields) and if it has, then iterate the fields in loop and set a new array and then pass it to update query,

Answer (score 0):

When you say it's 'too difficult' what do you mean exactly?

Is it that the radio and checkbox are not being posted unless they are checked? If so this is standard behaviour and you could ensure they are always posted by having a hidden input field above the radio/checkbox with the same name eg:

```
<input name="yourCheckbox" type="hidden" value="0">
```

Then your actual checkbox would override this if checked

Answer (score 0):

I know that, but problem is when someone want to update info about radio and checkbox. I mean, user can create input form like radio checkbox but I can not send this and get back form database